# Change a box to a plot or plotshape

Tags: pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have this code for imbalance

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Fair Value Gaps
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Bullish
[bull_fvg, bull_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(show_fvg, fvg_usewidth, fvg_method, fvg_gapwidth, low, high[2], low > high[2] and close[1] > high[2])

bull_fvg_filled = bull_filled(bull_fvg, high[2])

//Bearish
[bear_fvg, bear_fvg_count] = imbalance_detection(show_fvg, fvg_usewidth, fvg_method, fvg_gapwidth, low[2], high, high < low[2] and close[1] < low[2])

bear_fvg_filled = bear_filled(bear_fvg, low[2])

if bull_fvg
    avg = math.avg(low, high[2])
    
    box.new(n-2, low, n + fvg_extend, high[2], border_color = na, bgcolor = color.new(bull_fvg_css, 80))
    line.new(n-2, avg, n + fvg_extend, avg, color = bull_fvg_css)
    
    
    
if bear_fvg
    avg = math.avg(low[2], high)

    box.new(n-2, low[2], n + fvg_extend, high, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.new(bear_fvg_css, 80))
    line.new(n-2, avg, n + fvg_extend, avg, color = bear_fvg_css)
```

I try to change the box.new by a plot like this but error :Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope

```
plotshape_bull = n-2, avg, n + fvg_extend, avg
plotshape(plotshape_bull, color = bull_fvg_css, "BB10 up", style=shape.labelup, color = #00ff0a, location = location.belowbar)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
plotshape(bull_fvg_count ? bull_fvg : na ,"Bull", style=shape.arrowup, color = #00ff0a, location = location.top, offset = -1)
plotshape(bear_fvg_count ? bear_fvg : na ,"Bear", style=shape.arrowdown, color = color.red, location = location.top, offset = -1)
```